# Registering iOS default user preferences in Qt

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I have the following Root.plist in my Settings.bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"          "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>TAP Engine Hostname: </string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>localhost</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>engineHostname</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The issue is, when I query the engineHostname value, it's a null string.  From my reading on the Apple developer pages, the default settings need to be registered in the user preferences database.  Can anyone suggest how this can be accomplished using Qt?

Comment: maybe you should take a look at `QSettings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.  I was looking for a "Qt way" to solve my problem, but Qt does provide a mechanism to do what I want.  Qt Allows the project files to contain Objective C files, and the Clang compiler allowed mixing C++ and Objective C.  The trick is the make sure the header file has a C++ interface.  I ended up with the following, which works:

```
//
//  UserPreferenceUtility.h
//  tap_new_display_app
//
//  Created by David Roscoe on 5/21/15.
//
//

#ifndef tap_new_display_app_UserPreferenceUtility_h
#define tap_new_display_app_UserPreferenceUtility_h

class QString;

class UserPreferenceUtility
{
public:

  /// register default preferences from plist file
  void registerDefaultPrefs(void);

  /// get currently stored engine hostname
  QString getEngineHostname(void);

private:  // methods

};

#endif
```

This provides the C++ interface.  The mixed-mode implementation is here:

```
//
//  UserPreferenceUtility.mm
//  tap_new_display_app
//
//  Created by David Roscoe on 5/19/15.
//
//

#include "UserPreferenceUtility.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <QtCore>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void UserPreferenceUtility::registerDefaultPrefs()
{
  NSDictionary* appDefaults = [NSDictionary
                               dictionaryWithObject:@"localhost" forKey:@"engineHostname"];

  if (appDefaults)
  {
    // the default value was found in the dictionary.  Register it.
    // wrapping this in an if.. clause prevents overwriting a user entered
    // value with the default value
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

QString UserPreferenceUtility::getEngineHostname()
{
  NSString* engine_hostname_pref = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"engineHostname"];
  return QString::fromNSString(engine_hostname_pref);
}
```

The C++ functions execute native Objective C calls to extract the preferences stored in the user preference database.